# Are there any communities in which the oleh still leins his own aliyah?

Tags: minhag, torah-reading, modern-times

It used to be that when someone got an *aliyah*, they would read their own Torah portion, and not have it read for them by the *ba'al kriyah*. This practice seems to have fallen by the wayside, as every synagogue I've been in has had a *ba'al kriyah* -- (almost) no one will read their own *aliyah*, except for certain *minyanim* where the *kriyah* is split up, and the *gabbai* will give each *ba'al kriyah* an *aliyah*...which is still not the same as "having each *oleh* read their own *aliyah*."

Are there any modern-day communities where the custom is still to have each *oleh* read their own *aliyah*?

Comment: I can't say the custom is for everyone to read their own aliyah, but in many Mizrachi communities, if the oleh can, he will.

Comment: @Scimonster Interesting; I haven't been to many Mizrachi batei knesset. See also [Isaac Moses' answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/56860/5323).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have seen this practice in action in a [Yemenite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yemenite_Jews) shul in [Rosh Ha'ayin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosh_HaAyin), Israel. I got called up for an *'aliya*, and the gabbai leined on my behalf, but I was the ignorant exception.

They also had a boy reading *[Targum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Targum)* after (if I recall correctly) each *'aliya*.

Comment: Right, i've seen the Targum done at Teimani shuls also. Not that i've been to any very often.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen Targum done. I need to get out more (read: go to a Teimani shul at least once). cc @Scimonster

Comment: I saw this at a Yemenite Shul in Binyamina, Israel. That week was Parashat Vayishlach and the Meturgeman skipped the translation of Maaseh Reuven.

Comment: @DoubleAA.  I have been to the same Teimani shul in Binyamina and being an am ha'aretz had to ask what in the world was going on.  The Torah service was long, but it started to go faster after they passed out the Arak.